# Process a changing list using a higher-order function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there any way to process a changing list using higher-order functions in Clojure and *not* using explicit recursion?  For example, consider the following problem (that I made up to illustrate what I have in mind):

> Problem: Given a list of unique integers of unknown order.  Write a
> that produces an output list as follows:
>
> 1. For any even integer, keep the same relative position in the output list.
> 2. For any odd integer, multiply by ten, and put the new number at a new
>    place: at the back of the original list.
>
> So for example, from original vector [1 2 3 4 5], we get: [2 4 10 30 50]

I know how to solve this using explicit recursion.  For example:

```
(defn process
  [v]
  (loop
   [results []
    remaining v]
   (if (empty? remaining)
    results
    (if (even? (first remaining))
     (recur (conj results (first remaining)) (rest remaining))
     (recur results (conj (vec (rest remaining)) (* 10 (first remaining))))))))
```

This works fine.  Notice that `remaining` changes as the function does its work.  I'm doing the housekeeping here too: shuffling elements from `remaining` to `results`.  What I would like to do is use a higher-order function that does the housekeeping for me.  For example, if `remaining` did not change as the function does its work, I would use `reduce` and just kick off the process without worrying about `loop` or `recur`.

So my question is: *is there any way to process an input (in this example, `v`) that changes over the course of its operations, using a higher-order function?*

(Side note for more context: this question was inspired by [Advent of Code 2020, Question 7, first part](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/7#part1).  There, the natural way to approach it, is to use recursion.  I do [here](https://github.com/curiousyogurt/AdventOfCode2020/blob/main/src/advent2020/day7a.clj) (in the `find-all-containers` function; which is the same way other have approached it, for example, [here](https://github.com/zelark/AoC-2020/blob/master/src/zelark/aoc_2020/day_07.clj) in the `find-outer-bags` function, or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFLZqXMeIpw) in the `sub-contains?` function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier to do without recursion than with it! Since you only care about the order of evens relative to other evens, and likewise for odds, you can start by splitting the list in two. Then, map the right function over each, and simply concatenate the results.

```
(defn process [xs]
  (let [evens (filter even? xs)
        odds (filter odd? xs)]
    (concat evens (map #(* 10 %) odds))))
```

As to the advent of code problem, I recommend working with a better data structure than a list or a vector. A map is a better way to represent what's going on, because you can easily look up the properties of each sub-bag by name. If you have a map from bag color to contents, you can write a simple (recursive) function that asks: "Can color `a` contain color `b`?" For leaf nodes the answer is no, for nodes equal to the goal color it's yes, and for branches you recurse on the contents.

Comment: I like your solution to my sample a lot; but I'm not sure it addresses the general question that I am asking.  In general, I'm asking if you would normally solve something such as `(reduce f xs)` but the `xs` need to change as you apply `f` — is there a way to address this?  Or is what you are saying is that it depends on shifting how one thinks about the individual problem?

Comment: Yes, think about the problem differently, or ask a more specific question. "Reduce a list, but the list is allowed to change" is basically as broad as "Implement a function that takes a list as input". There's no general solution to that task.

Comment: You could make the problem statement less confusing by avoiding the word "change".  In Clojure nothing changes.  Lists are immutable.  The f that you give to map or reduce is a pure function that makes a new thing out of one or two old things.  However, there is no limit to the nature of the new thing that f can produce!  For example consider the different shapes of things produced by `(reduce + ...)` and `(reduce str ...)` and `(reduce into ...)`.